# Can't manage to render any PrimeNG UI component

Tags: angular, angular-cli, primeng

Okay so I'm just trying to install PrimeNG UI components for Angular 4, and there's no way I can manage do do it.

I'm following this official "[PrimeNG setup](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)", but I find the instructions very poor and misleading.

I'm using Angular-CLI v1.1.1, Node v7.9.0

**Step 1 :**

I create a new Angular-CLI project with

```
ng new test-primeNG
cd test-primeNG
npm install primeng --save
```

`ng serve` : OK on localhost:4200

**Step 2**

They say to `import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/primeng';` and `import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';`

It's not said where, but I suppose this goes into `app.module.ts`.

It's also not said (very poor documentation), but I assume I have to do something like

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AccordionModule
  ],
```

Compilation OK, `ng serve` still OK

**Step 3**

Since I imported the `accordion` module, I try to create an accordion. No need for CSS for now, I'm just trying to not get errors in the console.

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">Content 1</p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">Content 2</p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">Content 3</p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

I already get a sh*tload of errors in the console, starting with :

> Template parse errors: 'p-accordionTab' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'p-accordionTab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'p-accordionTab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.

Then the documentation talks about some Angular 4 animation stuff (?) and add `import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';` which is already generated by Angular-CLI in `app.module.ts` so I have no idea why this is here.

Bottom line : after struggling all morning, I still don't have a clue about how to render any PrimeNG component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the `SharedModule`:

(I needed it to use `DataTableModule`, maybe it's not needed for accordion and this is just a different issue?)

```
import {AccordionModule, SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
...
imports: [
    ...
    AccordionModule,
    SharedModule,
    ...
]
```

Comment: Oh yes that was it. I got a few more errors like `Include BrowserAnimationsModule in your project`, but in the end it's starting to work. Thanks! They seriously need to work on their doc... -_-'